# Postgres UNION with ORDER BY and LIMIT

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM public."LamcApiCalls" WHERE generalstatuscode=0 AND sendondate < NOW() AND push = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM public."LamcApiCalls" WHERE generalstatuscode=0 AND sendondate < NOW() AND push IS NULL ORDER BY random() LIMIT 50
```

It's failing because of the ORDER BY and LIMIT on the second query. Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks

Comment: May be you can avoid UNION by coalesce(push,1). Null values replaced by 1 or any digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the second query into a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM public."LamcApiCalls" WHERE generalstatuscode=0 AND sendondate < NOW() AND push = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    * 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM public."LamcApiCalls" WHERE generalstatuscode=0 AND sendondate < NOW() AND push IS NULL ORDER BY random() LIMIT 50
) s
```

Comment: If that is what he wants (the ORDER and LIMIT to apply to just that one query branch, not the whole UNION), then all he has to do is parenthesize the 2nd query.  No need to wrap it in the subquery.

Comment: Uh, great one! Thanks, I didn't even know!